# How can I invoke a sharepoint workflow using sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have an asp.net web app that can insert data into a sharepoint library using sharepoint web services.  How can I trigger the workflow that associates with the library after I insert data.

If I cannot trigger the workflow this way, then I have to upload a document into the Type column then it will trigger the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function passing the specified parameters:

```
    static void StartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem, SPSite spSite, string wfName)
    {
        SPList parentList = listItem.ParentList;
        SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = parentList.WorkflowAssociations;
        foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection)
        {
            if (association.Name == wfName)
            {
                association.AutoStartChange = true;
                association.AutoStartCreate = false;
                association.AssociationData = string.Empty;
                spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, association, association.AssociationData);
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll also need

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
```

It worked for my VS app.

Comment: Is there a sharepoint web service end point that can be used to achieve the same purpose?  My web app does not have sharepoint objects, just sharepoint web services.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Why can't you create SP objects? You just need to know your site address and list name. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: My website is not a sharepoint project, just an asp.net website that uses sharepoint web services.  And the website is on a non-sharepoint server.  It would be good if I can keep the abstraction.

Comment: Your StartWorkflow method does not take in item id or row id so how does it know which library item to work on?

Comment: It takes the item itself (the first argument). You find it using: SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(itemId);

Comment: Is your VS project a sharepoint project?  I thought you have to have sharepoint project in order to use sharepoint library.

Comment: No, it's a console app.